# Translucent worms are growing on my moss, will they move onto other plants?

Tags: indoors, worms, moss

I started growing moss indoors and I now see a strange discoloration with a few tiny translucent worms on it.

The moss is in an open jar and I mist it twice a day and keep it moist.

How can I eliminate the worms? Is there a risk of the worms moving to other plants in the house, or moss in other parts of the house?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These translucent worms are almost certainly the larvae of **Fungus Gnats** and, if you look closely, you may see the adults running across the soil. They are attracted by damp conditions and their presence suggests that you have been keeping your moss too moist. They also thrive on potting soil that is high in organic matter - and on peat moss!

I have done a quick online search and, apparently, they rarely harm healthy houseplants but, given the right conditions, will breed and spread to your other plants, and even to the rest of your house.

You can control them by:

- ensuring that your plants are not over-watered; allow the potting compost to dry out a little between waterings, so that it is *slightly* damp to the touch, but *never wet*;
- spraying the soil with neem oil or an insecticide of pyrethrins.

The following articles/video should prove helpful:

- [Little Transparent Worms](http://www.ehow.com/info_8793627_little-translucent-worms-plant-pot.html)
- [Fungus Gnat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus_gnat)
- [How to Control fungus Gnats](http://www.ehow.com/video_4774744_control-fungus-gnats-indoor-plants.html)
- [Flies in the Home](http://lancaster.unl.edu/pest/resources/flies015.shtml)